# How to automatically open the first collapsibleset set(accordion)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set and when the page is loaded, I wanna open the first collapsible set automatically.

How I do that in jquerymobile?

Comment: first `collapsible` or `collapsibleset`?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) You can use `data-collapsed=false`

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also do it through code on the `pageinit` event :

```
$("#myCollapsibleSet").children(":first").trigger("expand");
```

Assuming `#myCollapsibleSet` to be the ID of your collapsible set.