# How to programatically expand a Jquery's data-role="collapsible"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need your help in grammatically expanding a Jquery's Collapsable div

I have tried with number of options

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/20/

I have tried as following

```
<div data-role="content" class="data">
    <div class="my-collaspible" id="first" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Header 1</h3>

        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="my-collaspible" id="second" data-inset="false" data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Header 2</h3>

        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var id = 'first';
   $("#" + id).trigger('expand').collapsible("refresh");
 });
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'grammatically expanding'. Its a little vague on what your having trouble with/trying to do.

Comment: You mean something like in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300103/how-to-automatically-open-the-first-collapsibleset-setaccordion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use following option : **[`collapsible`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#option-collapsed)**,

```
$("#" + id).collapsible( "option", "collapsed", false );
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/22/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/37/

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div id="first" data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Header 1</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="second" data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Header 2</h3>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Test" id="btn1" />
```

and JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#first").collapsible('expand');

   //test
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
     $("#first").collapsible('collapse');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`("#myCollapsible").collapsible("expand");`

This worked for me when using jQuery 1.11.1 and JQM 1.4.5